# VB Authenticate User In Outlook Web App

Tags: vb.net, aspose

I currently have a mail system using Microsoft's exchange server (OWA). I am trying to authenticate a user and send an email using pure Visual Basic code.

I have been trying to use a library called Aspose, however; I have no idea if I'm on the right track. I can not get it to work and I am not sure (since this is a company mail server) whether it's the server or it's my code.

Currently I have,

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ' Create instance of ExchangeClient class by giving credentials
        Dim client As Aspose.Email.Exchange.ExchangeClient = New Aspose.Email.Exchange.ExchangeClient("https://MAILSERVER.com/username/", "username", "password", "https://MAILSERVER.com/")

        ' Create instance of type MailMessage
        Dim msg As Aspose.Email.Mail.MailMessage = New Aspose.Email.Mail.MailMessage()
        msg.From = "username@MAILSERVER.com"
        msg.To = "receivingemail@gmail.com"
        msg.Subject = "test"
        msg.HtmlBody = "test"

        ' Send the message
        Try
            client.Send(msg)
            Console.WriteLine("made it")
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("failed")
        End Try
    End Sub
```

I have obviously changed the username, password, and server name fields to generic ones but with (what I think is the right credentials) the output is always `failed`.

Can anybody help me out please?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I use:

```html
    Public Shared Function SendEMail(MailMessage As System.Net.Mail.MailMessage) As String
 ErrorMess = ""
 ' Default the from address, just in case is was left out. 
 If MailMessage.From.Address = "" Then
     MailMessage.From = New Net.Mail.MailAddress("donotreply@MAILSERVER.com")
 End If
 ' Check for at least one address
 If MailMessage.To.Count = 0 AndAlso MailMessage.CC.Count = 0 AndAlso MailMessage.Bcc.Count = 0 Then
     ErrorMess = "No Addresses Specified"
     Return ErrorMess
 End If
 ' Create a SMTP connedction to the exchange 2010 load balancer.
        Dim SMTPClient As New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("MAILSERVER.com")
 Try
     Dim ValidUserCredential As New System.Net.NetworkCredential
     ValidUserCredential.Domain = "MAILSERVER.com"
     ValidUserCredential.UserName = My.Resources.EmailUserName
     ValidUserCredential.Password = My.Resources.EmailPassword

     SMTPClient.UseDefaultCredentials = False
     SMTPClient.Credentials = ValidUserCredential
     SMTPClient.Send(MailMessage)
     Return "Mail Sent"
 Catch ex As Exception
            ErrorMess = ex.Message & " " & ex.InnerException.ToString
     Return ErrorMess
 End Try
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The ExchangeClient class is used to connect to Exchange server using the WebDav protocol and is used with Exchange Server 2003 and 2007. For OWA, you need to use the IEWSClient interface as shown in the following sample code. It has an Office365 test account that you can use to send a test email (the test account is solely for testing purpose and is not property of Aspose. I just created it for assisting you in testing the functionality). Please try it and if you face any problem, you may share the porblem on [Aspose.Email forum](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.email-product-family/188/showforum.aspx) for further assistance.

```
' Create instance of IEWSClient class by giving credentials
Dim client As IEWSClient = EWSClient.GetEWSClient("https://outlook.office365.com/ews/exchange.asmx", "UserTwo@ASE1984.onmicrosoft.com", "Aspose1234", "")
' Create instance of type MailMessage
Dim msg As New MailMessage()
msg.From = "UserTwo@ASE1984.onmicrosoft.com"
 msg.[To] = "receiver@gmail.com"
msg.Subject = "Sending message from exchange server"
msg.IsBodyHtml = True
msg.HtmlBody = "<h3>sending message from exchange server</h3>"

' Send the message
client.Send(msg)
```

I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.